# VSCode TypeScript problemMatcher `$tsc-watch` not watching

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsc, vscode-tasks, vscode-problem-matcher

I'm trying to avoid having to use `watch: true` in a `tsconfig.json` configuration.

Through VSCode's tasks I'm using the base problem matcher `$tsc-watch` but it's not launching `tsc` in watch mode when building. I'm adding `gulp` support and I see there is `gulp-watch` but I'd like to understand why `$tsc-watch` isn't working as I believe it should.

Comment: Are you using `"schema": 2.0`?

Comment: @AluanHaddad I am. I just figured out by looking at the VS Code typescript extension source

Comment: just checking because I ran into a weird issue when the schema wasn't explicitly set the other day

Answer (score 6):

I figured this out by looking at the `typescript` extension's `taskProvider.js`. In order for `tsc-watch` to function the task needed `option: "watch"` to be set.

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
            "isBackground": true,
            "problemMatcher": ["$tsc-watch"],
            "option": "watch",
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "silent",
                "focus": false,
                "panel": "shared"
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Interesting, is this documented? If not maybe send a PR

Comment: docs at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks